# Is the API to create Chromecast groups directly documented?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm looking for the API to create CC groups by directly sending the necessary JSON payloads to CC players. I don't want to use any cast SDK, I need something low level. Is this described somewhere?

I've already developped apps (https://github.com/philippe44/AirConnect) to directly talk to CC devices, so I'm familiar with the protocol but I can't find anywhere the grouping protocol and because it's all HTTPS I can't wireshark what's happening from another controller

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an API for developers to create cast groups.